# Android - how to know if animation does not run because view's parent is hidden?

Tags: android, android-animation

When I try run an animation on a view that belongs to a hidden layout, the animation never runs. That is a problem because the animation listener is in charge of changing the view's LayoutParams and since it is never called the view doesn't change and remains the same when the parent layout is finaly shown.

Is there a way to know if the animation does not run so that I can change the LayoutParam manualy ?

I'm looking for a generic solution, not something like checking the parent's visibility. The parent that is hidden could be any number of parent levels above.

Answer (score 1):

Such solutions do not exist.

If you use Visibility.GONE, your View not be measured. You need use Visibility.INVISIBLE if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you don't mention what kinds of your animation is. As I know, [Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) has two methods called *isRunning* and *isStarted*, you can choose one to get the state of your animation if your use it's subclasses [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html).